# Getimagesize() - read error

Tags: php, magento

So I'm doing some maintenance on other people's legacy code, and I've fixed some basic permissions issues, however now in an image uploader, I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error! in /home/kirby/public_html/members/upload_advanced.php on line 211
```

Now, the permissions for that directory are set to allow read, execution and write - what would cause that issue? Could it be that the uploader isn't correctly writing the information?

Comment: Are you *100% sure* that the file is there and that it's a valid image?

Comment: Well, I am attempting to upload the image - theoretically it should be uploading it and then attempting to read it. How would I see what image it was trying to read (figuring I'd have to look at the code to track it down)

Comment: A basic first test would be to print the value of `file_exists` for that file.

Comment: Apparently the file is empty, according to Windows File Viewer. Hrrrm. Interesting. The permissions for it should exist, though. Odd.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for it: 1. image not exists, 2. image too large such as 20000 width * 10000 height (I had seen once), 3 image uploaded but too big to save, which result in a broken image with 0 byte size. etc.

Comment: This was a classic case of not understanding the error message. I'd 'created' the image with touch as I was just writing test code. So the error message was saying yep there's a read error because it was actually a zero sized file!!!

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this before, and for me it was a memory issue, failing in the method:

```
_getNeedMemoryForFile
```

Probably the safest bet is to wrap to try-catch and handle the exception as gracefully as possible.